# Paso de parametro java

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, http

Estoy intentado pasar por parametro una parte de una respuesta Json, pero a la hora de usarlo aparece como null. Os dejos los codigos.

Llamada post

```
@PostMapping("/hostedTokenizationSession")
    public static CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse hostedTokenizationSession() throws IOException, InterruptedException, AuthenticationException {

        //Crear un nuevo objeto HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(getRequest(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        log.info(String.format(" CREATEHOSTEDTOKENIZATION | RESPONSE %s",response.body()));


        return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(response.body(), CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse.class);
    }
```

Metodo para construir la Url

```
public static String getUrl(CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse response){
        String Url=String.format("%s/%s/%s/%s", Base_Url, PspId,HostedTokenizations,response.getHostedTokenizationId());
        log.info(String.format(" GETHOSTEDTOKENIZATIONSESSION | URL %s", Url));
        return  Url;
    }
```

Clase CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse

```
@Data
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse {

    @JsonProperty("hostedTokenizationUrl")
    private String hostedTokenizationUrl;

    @JsonProperty("partialRedirectUrl")
    private String partialRedirectUrl;

    @JsonProperty("hostedTokenizationId")
    private String hostedTokenizationId;

    @JsonProperty("invalidTokens")
    private String[] invalidTokens;

    @JsonProperty("expiredCardTokens")
    private String[] expiredCardTokens;

}
```

Me podeis decir porque cuando intento usar la Url, el valor de hostedTokenization sale como null?
Gracias

Comment: Hola no tienes ningun valor "hostedTokenization"

Comment: El valor llega con la llamada POST

Comment: Cuando mencionas `hostedTokenization` te refieres a `hostedTokenizationUrl` o a `hostedTokenizationId`? Porque no veo ninguna variable que se llame `hostedTokenization` en el código que estás mostrando.